# Finding circumference of a circle given its area

Tags: geometry, circles, area

So, I'm learning mathematics from the beginning & currently I'm learning basic geometry from Khan Academy.

I'm trying to find the circumference of a circle when its area is 9π units, by applying formula I learnt in this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-jqWW22FMdI

I found that if area of circle is 9π units its circumference must be 6π.

Here's what I did:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYTUI.jpg

Is my calculation right or wrong?

Comment: yes, it is correct!

Comment: I think you want $4\pi\cdot 9\pi$ on the left in the second line.

Comment: @David Mitra My bad, yes I want that. So, its correct?

Answer (score 1):

$$a=\pi r^2,c=2\pi r\to c=\sqrt{4\pi^2r^2}=\sqrt{4\pi a}$$

and

$$\sqrt{4\pi\cdot9\pi}=6\pi.$$

---

Also

$$a=\frac{c^2}{4\pi}$$ and
$$r=\sqrt{\frac a\pi}=\frac c{2\pi}.$$

Comment: Is it necessary to write times symbol between 4π and 9π in radical?

Comment: @Shams: $\sqrt{4\pi9\pi}$ is ugly.

Comment: OK, Thanks ... !

Answer (score 0):

$circumference^2 = 4×\pi×area$